# Export pdf UTF-8 encoding

Tags: javascript, jspdf, aspnetboilerplate, pdfmake, jspdf-autotable

I have some trouble with exporting data to pdf with arabic characters
, **the encoding is incorrect**

I tried [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) with [jsPDF-AutoTable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) plugin, and i tried [pdfMake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/) But the problem still exists

In addition, I am using ASP.Net Boilerplate v3.2.4 as a backend, Angularjs v1.7.5

i want to export ui-grid data to PDF

Here look at my angularjs code:

```
vm.exportPdf = function () {
            var columns = [];
            var rows = [];

            // copy ui-grid's titles to pdf's table definition:
            var allColumnDefs = vm.gridOptions.columnDefs;
            for (var columnIdx in allColumnDefs) {
                var columnDef = allColumnDefs[columnIdx];
                if (columnDef.name !== 'actions') {
                    var newColumnDef = {
                        title: columnDef.displayName,
                        dataKey: columnDef.name
                    };
                    columns.push(newColumnDef); 
                }
            }

            // copy ui-grid's actual data to pdf's table:       
            var allRecords = vm.gridOptions.data;
            for (var recordIdx in allRecords) {
                var record = allRecords[recordIdx];
                var newRow = {};
                for (var columnIdx1 in allColumnDefs) {
                    var columnDef1 = allColumnDefs[columnIdx1];
                    var value = record[columnDef1.name];
                    if (value !== null) {
                        newRow[columnDef1.name] = value;
                    }
                }
                rows.push(newRow);
            }

            var docName = 'myFile.pdf';
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
            doc.autoTable(columns, rows, { styles: { fontSize: 8.5 } });
            doc.save(docName);
        };
```

**OUTPUT arabic characters look like this:**

```
þÿ41C) 'DG1E DD-H'D'
```

so my question here is whether anyone has experienced this problem and what is the solution for it.

or are there other libraries or plugins to exporting to PDF but support UTF-8 and arabic characters.

Thanks.